# What is the training score used for?

Tags: machine-learning

This is a pretty basic question. However, I read that the training score isn't useful in machine learning.

From what I can tell, the training score only tells us if we have an overfit model. [E.g. if we have a training score of 100, something probably went wrong].

But are there any other reasons to need a training score?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. It's often a good sign that your training and test scores are relatively close.  For applications like natural language processing where you have a lot of out-of-vocabulary issues and very rare features, this is less attainable, but it's something to keep in mind as you manage model complexity.
2. It's very useful for deciding how to improve your model.  If there are a lot of cases you can't get right in training, it's useful to look at them to decide how to improve your model.
3. Assuming you've tuned regularization reasonably well, looking at the training score can help you prevent overfitting.  Every time you make a decision based on your test set, it gets approximately 1 bit smaller, effectively (or slightly more or less if you had a strong prior for the decision).  Therefore, it's useful to avoid looking at your test set too much, and to rather use it to validate larger issues like levels of overfitting, rather than individual feature additions, etc.